# Radical Axis of Collinear Points.

Tags: geometry

If I have three collinear points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, such that define a three different circles that pass through a point, then this three circles can define the same radical axis??

I think this a corollary of radical point, since *"Given three circles with noncollinear centers, the three radical axes of the circles taken in pairs are distinct concurrent lines".*

**Definition:** The radical axis of two circles is the locus of points at which tangents drawn to both circles have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

If their centers are collinear then the radical axes of any two is perpendicular to the common line, so the three radical axes are parallel to each other. In projective geometry we say that they intersect at infinity. If your three circles all go through one point then the three radical axes coincide with each other, passing through that point yet perpendicular to the line connecting the centers.

Comment: Then there is a second point, which is symmetrical about the line connecting the center of the circles.

Comment: why you mentioned the projective geometry? anyway very nice answer

Comment: @pablocn_ right that's true too